# InProc Session or save to database (using EF4.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net

While rebuilding a site I'm having a rethink on various aspects of my site.

One thing my current site does is store the shopping cart in session (InProc) through the various page requests of the buy process.

I'm thinking of moving away from using the session state and instead saving the cart to a database using Entity Framework where necessary.

Will I see a massive impact on performance in storing the cart this way?

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? InProc is generally preferred if your application is hosted on a single server and not part of a farm.

Comment: It was because I was having difficulty writing back to my database an object I'd already saved using EF that had then been stored in session. I ended up with an ObjectStateManager exception. See my last comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425983/ef4-1-how-to-deal-with-items-being-added-to-an-objects-collection

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't notice any performance difference by using a database to store your cart.  The plus point is that should your site take off and you get 10,000 hits a day your app will be able to scale :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a performance hit for storing data in the database?  Yes.  Are your users likely to notice?  Probably not.  Can this and all of the other little data calls your application makes add up to a noticeable difference to your users?  Definitely.  Like most everything, you need to balance the needs, benefits and resources.

I would first ask why you want to store your shopping cart in the database.  The reasons that jump to mind include web farm scenarios and persistence in case of w3wp resets or failures.

There are a few solutions for the web farm scenario: out-of-process session mode, database session mode, or use sticky sessions with in-process mode.  Check out the [ASP.NET session modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) for more info.

If all you're trying to do is persist your cart or protect it from in-memory volatility, you could just move your session state to the database as a quick to implement solution, but you could also go to explicit database tables.  Size of session, size of shopping cart data, network and hardware performance and many other aspects of your system could affect your results.  So measure, change, measure, compare.

Comment: Heh, after your other responses, looks like this won't help you much.  Takes me a while to write everything out sometimes.  Did you try reattaching objects pulled from session to your new service context?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure a new context is created each time the repository methods are called. After doing some testing it seemed to me to be the fact that I was recreating the objects from session that caused the duplicate key exception in ObjectStateManager

Comment: Hi Chuck. I think I found some related information to the ObjectStateManager issue here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/89b7087a-1b08-4fe0-9cc3-68986fe89a74/

Comment: Seems like you're on the right path then.  I recall NHibernate had an Attach method to use existing entities with a new data context.  Makes sense then that EF has a similar concept.